# Encoding xls file when requested rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, xls

I am using a html table definition as template to export to xls in rails. It is described here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

I have an XLS file generator, it works correctly, when requesting from browser it downloads the file and shows it in Excel with right encoding. When requesting from HTTP client I receive correct Russian text too. I want to attach this file to the email, so I make a request via [ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html):

```
session.get('issues#index', {format: :xls,})
```

and as a result in session.response.body there are question marks instead of Russian text. And

```
encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "")
```

doesn't help, it simply changes nothing.
What can be the reason? or maybe smb. tell me another way to attach the file to avoid such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: send http header Accept-lenguages=ru-RU

resulting query:

```
session.get('issues#index', {format: :xls}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'ru-RU'})
```